# Changing Sigma Limits for Proof

Tags: self-study

This is from an assignment where we had to prove the mean of a log-series distribution where to prove it, the limits on the sigma notation needed to be changed
$E[X] = \Sigma_{x=1}^{\infty}x\times-\frac{1}{log(1-\theta)}\times\frac{\theta^x}{x}$
$E[X] = \Sigma_{x=1}^{\infty}-\frac{1}{log(1-\theta)}\times{\theta^x}$
$E[X] = \Sigma_{x=0}^{\infty}-\frac{1}{log(1-\theta)}\times{\theta^{x+1}}$

Then, using the sum of a geometric series here, we get:
$E[X] = -\frac{1}{log(1-\theta)}\times\frac{\theta}{1-\theta}$

Is this the correct way to change the limit on Sigma notation?

Comment: The calculations seem correct to me but you need to make sure $0<\theta<1$ .

Comment: As it is from the log-series distribution, that is true

Thanks for the feedback

Comment: As with almost all "yes or no" questions here, if a question is phrased this way and the answer might be yes, then "yes" doesn't allow us to post an answer (a "no" at least allows an explanation that might go longer than a sentence or two), which makes this sort of question more or less unsuitable for SE sites. Can you rephrase in such a way as to make a longer answer possible?